# Firebase: Could not find the Android Application module. Only Android Application Modules can be connected to Firebase online projects

Tags: firebase

When I try to connect with firebase service I am getting the error

```
Firebase: Could not find the Android Application module. Only Android Application Modules can be connected to Firebase online projects. Create a new Android Application Module or create/import a different Android Studio project.
```

[image]